# Linear transformation of a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a hyperplane $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|a^Tx=b\}$, and a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

For all $x$, we make a transformation $y=Mx$, and I would like to obtain the image of the hyperplane under this transformation in the form of equality constraints.

If $M$ is invertible, the transformed hyperplane is $\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n|a^TM^{-1}y=b\}$.

Is there an algorithmic way to compute the transformed figure for general $M$, including the case where $M$ is singular?

Comment: A hyperplane is a flat thing in your space that is "lacking" only one dimension. Please be more specific.

Comment: It can be a subspace of any dimension $\lt n$. Find a basis for the hyperplane and transform that.

Comment: Is there any algorithmically more efficient way of transforming the normal vector?